# postgresql Date vs java Instant

Tags: java, postgresql, date, java.time.instant

Suppose I have a field in Java app of type `Instant` and store it in PostgreSQL database as type [`DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html).

If I save for example `21.02.2019 14:03:59` it will be stored as `21.02.2019` but how will it be re-translated when I read from database?

Will it be:

- `21.02.2019 00:00:00.000` or
- `21.02.2019 23:59:59.000` ?

PS. I know I should use `Timestamp` instead :)

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

- A `DATE` column in a SQL-standard-compliant database such as Postgres stores only a date, no time and no zone.
- Use `LocalDate` for a date-only value, without time and zone.
- To get a `LocalDate` from an `Instant`, specify the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone) through which you want to determine a date.
- If you want to store a moment (as represented by an `Instant` object), use the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` rather than `DATE`.

## Details

### `Instant` is in UTC

An `Instant` object represents a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), always in UTC. In other words, a moment with an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

### Determining date requires time zone

Getting a date from an `Instant` therefore requires a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) (a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html)). A moment after midnight in Paris France is a new date, say **the 23rd**, while in Montréal Québec it is still “yesterday” **the 22nd**. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

So if you meant the date as seen in Québec, specify the time zone `America/Montreal".

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

You said your database column is of type [`DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html). In Postgres, like the SQL standard, that means a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.

To store only the date, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, extract a `LocalDate`. The word “local” means *any* locality or *all* localities, but *not* any one particular locality.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

### JDBC 4.2

Exchange that `LocalDate` via a placeholder in a prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

### Date stored, date retrieved

> how will it be re-translated when I read from database?
>
> Will it be:
>
> 21.02.2019 00:00:00.000 or …

This question makes no sense. When you read a `DATE` from a SQL-standard compliant database like Postgres, you get a date, only a date — no time-of-day, and no time zone.

If you store a `LocalDate` of value `2019-02-21` in a `DATE` column, you get back the same: a `LocalDate` of value  `2019-02-21`.

### First moment of the day

If you want to add a time-of-day for the first moment of the day, let *java.time* determine that for you. On some dates in some time zones, the day does *not* begin at 00:00:00 but may instead start at a time like 01:00:00.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;  // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object set to the first moment of the day as seen on that date in that time zone. May or may not be the time 00:00:00.
```

### UTC

If you want to extract a date from your `Instant` using UTC as your time zone, meaning an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, use the `OffsetDateTime` class with the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how you're reading it. `Instant` and SQL `DATE` are not equivalent, and I don't know any reliable library that would even allow you to read `DATE` to `Instant`. If you write your own code that allows this, then you can make it fill the hour, minute, second and milliseconds in any way you want to, even if it doesn't make sense (so the real answer to your question would be "neither" unless **you** explicitly write code to transform `java.sql.Date` to `java.time.Instant`).

If you're designing software that stores instants as dates, then your design is flawed. Either use `LocalDate` on Java side, or `TIMESTAMP` in the database.

Comment: Yes, it was definitely flawed due to a mistake and is now fixed. I was just curious how did it work that I didn't spot it earlier. I have Hibernate under the hood, which probably translates DATE to `21.02.2019 23:59:59.999` version.

Comment: If Hibernate doesn't mind saving `Instant` to `DATE` without complaining, I'm honestly a bit disappointed.

Comment: Not being a PostgreSQL user I would suppose the `timestamp with time zone` would be the most correct datatype for a Java `Instant`?

Comment: @OleV.V. indeed.